# Wrong information showing in Xlwt export in Django

Tags: python, django, excel

I´m having a hard time with this. I have a button at the bottom of a page. This page shows the render information of a bill, every bill is different so this information changes all the time. The button is there so the users can download the bill as an Excel file. For the download i have this code in my views.py:

```
def descarga(request,id_factura):
    fact = Factura.objects.get(pk= id_factura)
    book = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf8')
    sheet = book.add_sheet('report')   
    alignment = xlwt.Alignment()

    alignment.horz = xlwt.Alignment.HORZ_LEFT
    alignment.vert = xlwt.Alignment.VERT_TOP
    style = xlwt.XFStyle() # Create Style
    style.alignment = alignment # Add Alignment to Style

# write the header
    header = ['Cliente', 'Fecha de Factura', 'Tipo de Factura', 'Numero de Factura',      'Descripcion', 'Subtotal', 'IVA', 'Precio']
    for hcol, hcol_data in enumerate(header):
    sheet.write(0, hcol, hcol_data, style=xlwt.Style.default_style)

# write your data, you can also get it from your model
    data = {
        "Cliente": fact.nombre_cliente,
        "Fecha de Factura":fact.fecha_factura,
        "Tipo de Factura": fact.tipo_Factura,
        "Numero de Factura": fact.numero_De_Factura,
        "Descripcion": fact.descripcion,
        "Subtotal": fact.importe_sin_iva,
        "IVA": fact.iva,
        "Precio": fact.importe_Total,
           }

    for row, row_data in enumerate(data, start=1): # start from row no.1
        for col, col_data in enumerate(row_data):
             sheet.write(row, col, col_data)


    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=report.xls'
    book.save(response)
    return response
```

what i´m getting are the correct Headers, but the information that i´m trying to get with the Data dictionary is not showing, instead im getting the names of the headers separated in columns letter by letter something like:

```
N   u   m   e   r   o       d   e       F   a   c   t   u   r   a
```

where every letter is a column in the excel file

So, how can i fix this and make the correct information to show up and not this.
Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug is in here:

```
for row, row_data in enumerate(data, start=1):
```

where your row is 1,2,3,4... and your row_data is key of data which is string and then the second loop is going on that string (key)

```
for col, col_data in enumerate('Numero de Factura'):
```

maybe try replacing:

```
for row, row_data in enumerate(data, start=1): # start from row no.1
        for col, col_data in enumerate(row_data):
             sheet.write(row, col, col_data)
```

by this:

```
for column, key in enumerate(header, start=1):
    sheet.write(1, column, data[key])
```

Comment: After adding this line: "for column, key in enumerate(header, start=1):
    sheet.write(1, column, data[key])" I´m getting a = "Unexpected data type <class 'apps.Administracion.models.Cliente'>"

Comment: Do i have to delete this line: "for row, row_data in enumerate(data, start=1):"??. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I´m still getting the Unexpected data type error. The Traceback shows this: File "C:\Users\Python\Desktop\TestScene\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Python\Desktop\TestScene\ExiAdmin\apps\Administracion\views.py" in descarga
  161.         sheet.write(1, column, data[key])

Comment: i think the problem is here= "sheet.write(1, column, data[key])"

Comment: problem is in your dictionary "data" `Unexpected data type error`, `fact.fecha_factur` is probably not a string try to convert **all** values in your dictionary "data" to str like `str(fact.fecha_factura)`

Comment: That Was great. Thank. One Last question. Now all the data appears but is not align on the right column and if i change the index of the field were to put the information to match the headers and the data i got a overwritting error. Any Last idea?.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what You are trying to do, can You paste Your stack trace.

Comment: .  The Headers and the information are good now,  i can see  all in the Excel file. The last problem is that i can't align the information of the bill with the column header. The header says 'Cliente' so the client name should be under this header. The thing is that if i change this part when i write the header: "Sheet.write(0,hcol, hcol_data... ) " to "Sheet.write. (1,hcol, hcol_data... ) "  to align the headers with the information i get an error. I Will show you the trace in 20 minutes (im on the traen now).  Thanks

Comment: Error: because function `sheet.write()` gets as parameters `row_number`, `column_number` and `data_to_fill` and your `row_number` value is same in more then one places in other words you are trying to put to the same row and column few values.

Comment: Align: don't know how to help, maybe put this style=xlwt.Style.default_style to sheet.write() for data, but I am guessing now.